# How to check present view controller in if Condition in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

```
   if (self.presentedViewController== _aimationViewController) {
         ScreenViewController *ScreenViewController = [[ScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScreenViewController" bundle:nil withBuddy:buddy andMainViewController:self];
        [ScreenViewController loadAndPresentWelcomeView];       
    }else{

   }
```

How to check the current view controller is running on the screen ?

Answer (score 1):

the `self.presentedViewController` is the view controller The view controller that is presented by this view controller or it is the ancestors in the view controller hierarchy.

so if u want to check the present view controller use `self` it is the current view controller.

**EDIT:**
u can also check like below

```
if ([self.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[ScreenViewConroller class]])
{

}
```

Comment: but i want to check if the (self.presentedviewcontroller==ScreenViewConroller) than i can do some actions